# How can I import/use two different versions of a library (pytorch) in one program in Python?

Tags: python, import, pytorch, conda, torch

I need to use two different versions of pytorch in different parts of the same python webserver. Unfortunately, I can't install them both on the same conda environment that I'm using. I've tried importing one of them from the path itself:

```
MODULE_PATH = "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py"
MODULE_NAME = "torch"
import importlib
import sys
spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(MODULE_NAME, MODULE_PATH)
module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
sys.modules[spec.name] = module
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Which works fine for importing a different version than the one in the active environment, but then I run into an error when trying to import the second one (I've tried simply 'import torch' and also the same as above):

```
File "/home/abc/anaconda3/envs/env2/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
    __all__ += [name for name in dir(_C)
NameError: name '_C' is not defined
```

Any ideas on how I can use both versions? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle, importing two libraries with the same name is not possible. Sure, it might be the case that you could do some import-sorcery and manage to do it. But keep in mind that `pytorch` is not a straightforward Python package.

Now, even if you manage to solve this, it seems extremely strange to me that you need for your own service two different versions. Having that situation will just be a headache for you in the long run. My advice would be to reconsider how you're doing it.

Without knowing your situation, I'd recommend splitting the web service into two. This will allow you to have two environments and the two versions of `pytorch` you need.

Comment: Yeah I currently have it working split up into two web services, was just trying to find out if there was a better way to get it done. Thanks!

Comment: It might be interesting to know exactly why you need two versions of pytorch running at the same time (as in describing in your question a bit more) . Also, if the reason you want to merge them is performance, perhaps you can look into other alternatives like using gRPC to communicate (I guess you're using json).

Comment: I imagine many situations where two version of PyTorch are needed, e.g.  two different neural networks trained on old and new versions.