# Loading Python module with custom virtual environment

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv

I have a special problem. I have a program, from where I need to load external packages. But those packages could have their own dependencies. So I want to load this package also with the created virtual environment from Python. Problem is, that I don't know how to load the virtual environment to Python PATH/modules.

**Example:**

```
loader.py
models
   MODEL_A
      __venv__
      main.py
```

main.py

```
import numpy

def test():
     return numpy.array()
```

loader.py

```
# Load main.py from MODEL_A
MODEL_A.test()
```

I don't have a problem with loading the Python module, I am doing it like this

```
def _load_python_file(python_file: Path):         
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location(python_file.stem, python_file)

    module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(module)

    return module
```

But the problem is with loading the virtual environment. I found a [library](https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/py-localimport) that should do such a thing, but there is a problem with C extensions libraries.

```
with localimport(str(env_path / 'lib' / 'python3.8' / 'site-packages')), 
    localimport(str(env_path.parent)):
    interface_module = _load_python_file(interface_file)
```

With this, I got always some problems like this

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Do you know about some other possibility how to do such a thing? I need to do it inside Python, cause I need classes from that package, so I can't load outside of Python.

Comment: shouldn't the library you try to import be also a package with it's requirements? So you install it into the project env and then you don't need to use importlib at all

Comment: I can't do it because those packages could have different versions of the same library (for example torch)

Comment: I agree here with Ignacio https://stackoverflow.com/a/63629416/1253121 it is a strange thing to do.. But maybe someone can help you : ) GL